# Unescape commands argument in typeout

Tags: terminal-output

I have a macro which uses `\typeout` to print messages. I would like to unescape these.

```
\newcommand{\mymessage}[1]{
  \typeout{#1}
}
```

Then `\mymessage{foo\#bar}` should print `foo#bar`. Right now it prints `foo\#bar`.

**Edit:**

Answers below show how to solve the specific problem of unescaping `\#` character. However, this was meant as an example only. I also need to unescape `\%` and any other such combination.

Comment: “Any other” is a bit too generic; can you make a list? Anyway, you asked for `\#`.

Comment: What I really want to do is to typeout url's which are passed to a latex command, such that they are without any escapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit to follow up on OP's modifications.

Perhaps this will be ok with your yet to be precisely specified yet unknown constraints:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mymessage}[1]{\bgroup\escapechar-1 \typeout{\detokenize{#1}}\egroup}

\begin{document}

\mymessage{foo\#bar\!foo\%hello\&world}
\end{document}
```

produces:

```
foo#bar!foo%hello&world
```

---

original answer

If you are not using `\mymessage` from inside macros, you could try

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mymessage}{\bgroup\lccode`~=`\\\lowercase{\let~\string}%
                        \catcode92 13 \mynoescapemessage}
\newcommand{\mynoescapemessage}[1]{\typeout{#1}\egroup}

\begin{document}

\mymessage{foo\#bar\!foo\hello\world}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

```
foo#bar!foohelloworld
```

Notice that the reason the thing is a bit complicated (I could have chosen catcode `9` (aka "ignore")) is to avoid:

```
foo##bar
```

due to special treatment by TeX of `#` tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Redefine `\#` (locally):

```
\newcommand{\mymessage}[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\#{\string##}%
  \typeout{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\mymessage{foo\#bar}
```

The output is

```
foo#bar
```

Be careful with protecting end-of-lines in your macro definitions.

Here is how you can add escape codes:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mymessage}[1]{%
  \begingroup\mymessage@escapes
  \typeout{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\mymessage@escapes}{%
  \edef\#{\string##}%
  \let\%\@percentchar % already provided by LaTeX
  \edef\{{\string{}\edef\}{\string}}%
  \edef\${\string$}%
}

\mymessage{\{foo\#{bar}\%\$\}}
```

Also note that balanced braces need not be escaped in a `\typeout`.

The output is

```
{foo#{bar}%$}
```

Comment: Please see my edit.